# The ý character in INSERT mode isn't printed

Tags: vim

## Issue description

I use VIM to take notes in Czech at university lectures. All special characters work fine except for the 'ý' character.

When I type it in INSERT mode, it isn't printed. Instead, it shifts the cursor to the left, which is very annoying.

The character is represented correctly when typed in the vim command line. So I suppose the character is misinterpreted as an INSERT mode movement command? Is this a bug?

## How to reproduce

Please temporarily install the Czech **QWERTZ** keyboard layout (careful, there is a programmer version of the layout, we need the regular one).

Typing the 'ý' character can be accomplished using either of these steps:

- The top number row is reserved for the most common special characters, press 7 without SHIFT to print it.
- Special characters can also be typed by first pressing and then letting go the '=' key (next to BACKSPACE) and then pressing the character you want to decorate with an accent.

## Wrapping up

Issue replication times: always

- Ubuntu 17.10

  - Terminal
  - GUI vim-gnome
- Bash on Ubuntu for Win 10

Running vim without vimrc solves the issue.
Link to my [vimrc](https://github.com/hailstorm75/MySetup/blob/master/.vimrc)

Any suggestion and/or workaround will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you quoting, and which keys exactly do you press to type ý? I can’t find it with Google.

Comment: I've added the STR

Comment: Does it happen in GUI mode? I can’t reproduce this, but it could be a specific terminal emulator [configuration]. Also try running with `[g]vim -u NONE` to rule out vimrc.

Comment: What OS are you using? It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Updated question with the additional information you requested.
@Ryan Your suggestion to rule out vimrc solved the issue. I'll link my vimrc

Comment: Oh, good. Try with `pathogen#infect` commented out then? That should determine whether it’s a plugin.

Comment: Relevant: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20995/21251

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older issue, but to anyone else struggling with this, it is an issue within the [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/) plugin, that has since gone silent and unmaintained. There's an [issue](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/317) for it.

If you don't want to scroll through the discussion, there's a fork of the plugin at https://github.com/lunarWatcher/auto-pairs which has the issue fixed. Since the original plugin is unmaintained, there's little hope of the fix being merged back, but I managed to switch to the fork with no apparent issues.

Comment: Obligatory note: certain keybinds may require [`let g:AutoPairsCompatibleMaps = 0`](https://github.com/LunarWatcher/auto-pairs/blob/6c1deb2fe8501e1c4de31732f04eaede31b9021d/doc/AutoPairs.txt#L1312-L1328) (permalink, the default may have changed if you're reading this long after this comment was made. Search the docs for the current state) to properly remap everything. The only thing that option does is switch from a meta-based keybind system (read: the source of all evil in insert mode) to a control-based system. I vaguely remember ý in particular to be sourced from some system

Comment: I removed or otherwise config-blocked, but I don't remember off the top of my head. Switching to a control-based system is, regardless, a guaranteed way to avoid any character conflicts

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviation:

```
iabbrev 'y ý
```

could be used to display the `ý` character in insert mode. Typing `'y` should result in `ý`.